# Getting "image" coordinates of picturebox in zoom mode

Tags: c#

I am using a zoomed picturebox. I want to retrieve the image Top-Left and Bottom-Right coordinates. But it is different from that of picturebox when the aspect ratio of the image doesn't match the picturebox. I wonder how I can get the image coordinates on the form.

Comment: You can use the pbox.ClientSize and the pbox.Image.size to calculate it.. Top-Left will always be (0,0).. What does _image coordinates on the form_ mean??

Comment: Top-left is *not* (0, 0) in zoom mode.  Just reason it out with a tall and narrow image.  Consider using reflection to access the [ImageRectangle property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,d19be1af32c23a82).

Answer (score 0):

Minus the `Image` size divided by 2 from the `PictureBox`size plus the `Image` size again.

This uses the `Size.Subtract Method (Size, Size)`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Size sizestep1 = Size.Subtract(new Size(PictureBox1.Image.Size.Width / 2, PictureBox1.Image.Size.Height / 2), PictureBox1.Size);
Size finalsize = Size.Add(sizestep1, PictureBox1.Image.Size);

// Convert to point.
Point BottomRightCoords = new Point(finalsize.Width, finalsize.Height);
```

And if you want to get the BottomRightCoords on the form, you have to add the `PictureBox` Location to it.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of mathematics suggested above + the code in the following link did the trick:
[How to retrieve zoom factor of a WinForms PictureBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473582/how-to-retrieve-zoom-factor-of-a-winforms-picturebox)